# What's the right way to data-load sample data from a CumulusCI dependency

Tags: cumulusci

I've spun up a bare-bones CumulusCI scratch org where `cumulusci.yml` says:

```yaml
  dependencies:
    - github: https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/EDA
    - github: https://github.com/SFDO-Community/Summit-Events-App
```

Once I spin it up, I'd love to load it with data from 1. [EDA's sample data](https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/EDA/blob/main/datasets/qa/QA-DsEdData.sql) and 2. either [this Summit events Sample data](https://github.com/SFDO-Community/Summit-Events-App/blob/master/datasets/package_beta/data.sql) or [this one](https://github.com/SFDO-Community/Summit-Events-App/blob/master/datasets/dev/data.sql) *(I haven't decided which yet)*.

I want to write up a proof of concept of:

> "**How to use [SFDMU](https://help.sfdmu.com/) and Python to grab your latest [validation table](http://etutorials.org/SQL/Database+design+for+mere+mortals/Part+II+The+Design+Process/Chapter+11.+Business+Rules/Validation+Tables/) data out of production and parse it into lines of code appropriate for a [CCI](https://cumulusci.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) `dataset.sql` file and a `mapping.yml` file.**"

*(Some colleagues have been struggling to keep the `dataset.sql` and `mapping.yml` files of a large in-house package's codebase up-to-date under rapid emergency changes to production data structures and data.   I think that SFDMU's features like `SELECT readonly_false` might be able to keep up with harsh realities and help serve as a "feeder" from production into `dataset.sql` and `mapping.yml` files.)*

But to start playing, I need a fake production org with a bunch of data in various "validation tables."

I don't feel like doing data entry, so spinning up a scratch org and data-loading in other people's sample datasets seems like a good substitute for an actual production org as I figure out what I want to write up as instructions for "prod to SQL."

Not sure how to dataload dependencies' datasets into a scratch org with CumulusCI, though?  Most of [the docs seem to be oriented toward when a dataset is part of your project](https://cumulusci.readthedocs.io/en/stable/data.html#a-name-data-load-dataset-a-load-dataset) rather than just wanting to play with one of your dependencies' sample data while you experiment architecturally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. Use the `sources` feature to run the `load_dataset` task [from a remote project](https://cumulusci.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html#tasks-and-flows-from-a-different-project). It would look something like this:

```yaml
sources:
    eda:
        github: https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/EDA
        
flows:
    my_flow:
        steps:
            ...
            5:
                task: eda:load_dataset
```

Alternately, if you're working at the CLI, you can do

```bash
$ cci task run eda:load_dataset --org some_org
```

and likewise for flows.

You can repeat this pattern as many times as needed for various remote repos.

Comment: Perfect -- I was also able to _only_ run add the `sources` to my YML file and then just hand-run a command like `cci task run summit:load_dataset -o mapping datasets/package_beta/mapping.yml -o sql_path datasets/package_beta/data.sql --org feature`.  _(Still playing w/ figuring out why EDA's data as `cci task run eda:load_dataset -o mapping datasets/qa/QA-release_regression_mapping.yml -o sql_path datasets/qa/QA-DsEdData.sql --org feature` doesn't like my org config -- something to do w/ communities.  It's always communities when weird deployment play fails in Salesforce.)_

Comment: Oh and wow OK I didn't realize how easy Snowfakery would be just stealing from [Summit Events's Snowfakery definition](https://github.com/SFDO-Community/Summit-Events-App/blob/master/datasets/dev/school_snowfakery_recipe.yml) and running `cci task run snowfakery --recipe my_fakes/my_first_snowfake.yml --org feature`.  _(Now why the org is yelling at me that I can't create an `Account` of type `Educational_Institution` is another question, but anyway...)_

Comment: That latter problem may be that you haven't run EDA's update_admin_profile to set the Record Types on your user. Edited my answer to note, as you observe, that it works from the CLI too.